# Empty the cell when it is disabled

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcell

I have a datagrid which uses Styles of DataGridCell type to disable some cells depending on value from another cell of same row.

Below is the XAML for Style

```
    <Style x:Key="testCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Segment}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Segment}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

This part is working as intended.

Now, as the columns are bound to VM properties which update the database accordingly, I need to empty the cell before disabling it so as to not to persist junk values in the DB.

Being new to C#, I'd prefer to use XAML for this purpose if possible.

How can this behavior be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Being new to C#, I'd prefer to use XAML for this purpose if possible.

XAML is a *markup* language. It cannot be used to clear any values from your source object.

What you should do is to clear the values in your data object as soon as the `Segment` property is set to 1 and you should do this programmatically, either in the class where `Segment` and the other properties are defined itself, or from the class that sets the `Segment` property.

You neither can't nor should clear any values of the underlying data object using a `DataTrigger`.

Comment: I was on my way to a solution using `ElementStyle` and `DataTrigger` for the concerned column, can you please explain further that why one **should not clear any values of the underlying data object using a `DataTrigger`** ?

Comment: What is there to explain? A data trigger check the value of some property and set a value of a *target* property.

Answer (score 0):

My trick: set `Foreground` to `Transparent`, that means the value is still there but not visible.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Segment}" Value="0">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: @PrabalKajla no, it just change the display of cell, the Foreground of celle to Transparent, when your property Segment == 0

Comment: Well..thanks for the solution but it won't solve the problem for me!